# Removing program icons from Launcher

Tags: unity, launcher, icons

I had three program downloads from "Ubuntu Software" fail to install on my computer.  Each program left an icon in the launcher with a note, "waiting to be installed".  Right click on the icon gives program name and option to lock to launcher.  No option to removed the icon from the launcher!  I cannot drag and drop the icons to any other place.

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on an AMD 64 CPU with two screens.  16.04 seems to be running well with no problems.  I just cannot clean up my launcher.

Comment: Perhaps information about which programs failed to install might be useful to us. Thank you for helping us help you! Please review http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask